# Implementing a find node function for singly linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I need to create a find node function for singly linked list in python.

Find: this method takes a value as a parameter, and returns the index of the first node which contains this value. If no nodes are found to contain this value, return False

So far I have:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, dataval=None):
    self.dataval = dataval
    self.nextval = None

class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self):
    self.headval = None
  def __str__(self):
    node = self.headval
    output = "[ "
    while(node != None):
      output = output + str(node.dataval) + ", "
      node = node.nextval
    if(len(output) > 2):
      output = output[:-2]
    return output + " ]"


  def find(self, val):
    current=self.headval 
    count=0
    while(current):
      if (count==val):
        return current
      count+=1
      current=current.nextval
    assert(False)
    return 0
```

I am not getting the correct output.Do you know what it could be? I know its because im comparing the value rather than index but how could I fix this?

Comment: You are comparing the value to the index, which makes no sense and you are returning a `Node` object, not the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. You need to look at `dataval` and not the index:

```py
  def find(self, val):
    current=self.headval 
    count=0
    while current != None:
      if (current.dataval==val):
        return count
      count+=1
      current=current.nextval
    assert(False)
    return -1      # return -1 instead of 0
```

Comment: `assert(False)` will normally throw an exception, so the last line isn't reached anyway.

Comment: Instead of using assert(False) and return -1 can I just say return False if the value doesn't exist.Because when I run it, it says AssertionError